# Add attribute to spring form element if condition true

Tags: java, spring, jsp

So I got this checkbox:

```
<form:checkbox id="someCheckbox" path="someCheckbox"/>
```

Now I would like to add an attribute - specifically `checked="checked"` if a condition is true. Is this possible without wrapping the entire element in an if statement?

**Basically what I want (results in an error):**

```
<form:checkbox id="someCheckbox" path="someCheckbox" ${isChecked ? 'checked=checked' : ''}/>
```

**Note** that adding the attribute `checked=""`, and making the value of it conditional will not work either, since checked=false or checked=' ' is treated as checked in modern browsers.

Comment: `${isChecked ? 'checked=checked' : ''}` should work fine if you have `<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>` in top of jsp.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in Tomcat 7/JSP 2.2/JSTL 1.2:

```
<form:checkbox id="someCheckbox" path="someCheckbox" 
    <c:if test="${isChecked}">
        checked="checked"
    </c:if> 
/>
```

Using the ternary operator like in your question should work with JSP >= 2.0:

```
<form:checkbox id="someCheckbox" path="someCheckbox" 
    ${isChecked ? "checked='checked'" : ""}
/>
```

Or you could use this:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${isChecked}">
        <c:set var="varChecked" value="checked='checked'"></c:set>
    </c:when>

    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="varChecked" value=""></c:set>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<form:checkbox id="someCheckbox" path="someCheckbox" 
    ${varChecked}
/>
```

Still less verbose and redundant than wrapping the entire form-tag in a c:if-tag.

Obviously you'll need to include the core taglib for any of these to work.

Comment: This won't work. You will get jsp compilation exception.

Comment: It's compiling just fine for me. What would the problem with it be?

Comment: It was breaking on the lines "weblogic.servlet.compilationexception .... no end tag found..." though there is end tag and jstl-1.2jar and standard jars are available at run time.

Comment: I'm getting an exception as well doing this, "Unterminated &lt;form:input tag"

Answer (score 2):

Include core jstl tag in your jsp:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

and then

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="someCheckbox" id="someCheckbox" <c:if test="${check your condition}">checked="checked"</c:if> />
```

Answer (score 1):

its better if you put the logic in controller

```
String checked=null;
if(condition)
checked="checked"
else
checked="";

modelMap.put("checkBoxChecked",checked);
```

return modelmap to view

and in view add as below

```
<form:checkbox id="someCheckbox" path="someCheckbox" ${checkBoxChecked}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since form:checkbox is bind with form through path attribute, it's enough if you set the value in your form object.

Eventually do it with javascript

Comment: It's not enough, since I want it to be checked if the value is NOT set (and in some other cases - hence the condition). I would like to deal with this without placing such logic partly in JavaScript.

Comment: why don't you move that logic to controller then?